# How to loop through array of objects and check if a value matches either a string in the object or a value in an array of items using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
    [{
    "title": "first footer",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "footer",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wobble"],
    "uId": "footerA"
  },{
    "title": "second footer",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "footer",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "footerB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "header",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "headerA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second header",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "header",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "headerB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "landingA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "landingB"
  },
  {
    "title": "third landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "landingC"
  },
  {
    "title": "first nav",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "navigation",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wobble"],
    "uId": "navA"
  },{
    "title": "first blog",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "blog",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "blogA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second blog sdf wicked",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "blog",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "blogB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "contact_button",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "contact_buttonA"
  },
  {
    "title": "first landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "content_blocA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "content_blocB"
  },
  {
    "title": "third landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "content_blocC"
  },
  {
    "title": "first nav",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "cover",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "coverA"
  }]
```

When I click on a button I want to be able to filter the objects in the array to return only matched objects that someone has searched for. For example if someone has typed 'land' the function should check if 'land' exists in the title of the component or if it exists in the hashtags array of that component.

I am using lodash to do this so would like to keep using this.

I have been able to do the test for the title but stuck on how to loop through the hashtags array as well when looking at the single component in the loop.

This is my code so far:

```
_.filter(this.components, function (component) {
  //Check if components title has 'wic' in the text or if 'wic' exists in the hashtags array
  if(_.includes(component.title, 'wic')) {
    console.log(component);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a `Boolean` from `Array.prototype.filter()`. You can use `Array.prototype.some()`, which also expects a `Boolean` return value, to check `hashtags` array.

```
var match = "land";
var re = new RegExp(match);
var res = this.components.filter(function(component) {
  return re.test(component.title) 
         || component.hashtags.some(function(tag) {
              return re.test(tag)
            })
});
```

using lodash `_.filter()`, `_.some()`

```
var match = "land";
var re = new RegExp(match);
var res = _.filter(this.components, function(component) {
console.log(component.title,  re.test(component.title) )
  return re.test(component.title) 
         || _.some(component.hashtags, function(tag) {
              return re.test(tag)
            })
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o8ervt0x/

Comment: Hi, this does work but was wondering if we could use lodash as I have used  it across my other pages and want to keep consistency

Comment: @saunders _"this does work but was wondering if we could use lodash"_ Why is using a library necessary? `.filter()` and `.some()` are defined at `Array.prototype`

Comment: I am learning loadash and want to keep consistency of how i do these type of functions as i already have others written in lodash so want to keep consistency

Answer (score 0):

it will give the object which has `land` word in their title

```js
savedViews=   [{
    "title": "first footer",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "footer",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wobble"],
    "uId": "footerA"
  },{
    "title": "second footer",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "footer",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "footerB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "header",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "headerA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second header",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "header",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "headerB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "landingA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "landingB"
  },
  {
    "title": "third landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "landingC"
  },
  {
    "title": "first nav",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "navigation",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wobble"],
    "uId": "navA"
  },{
    "title": "first blog",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "blog",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "blogA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second blog sdf wicked",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "blog",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "blogB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "contact_button",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "contact_buttonA"
  },
  {
    "title": "first landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "content_blocA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popin", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "content_blocB"
  },
  {
    "title": "third landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popn", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "content_blocC"
  },
  {
    "title": "first nav",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "cover",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/350x220",
    "hashtags": ["#popn", "#wibble"],
    "uId": "coverA"
  }]
var view = 'land';
var re = new RegExp(view);
var delete_id = savedViews.filter(function (el) {
    return   re.test(el.title);
});

//console.log(delete_id);
var view1 = 'popin';
var re1 = new RegExp(view1);
var delete_id1 = delete_id.filter(function (el) {
    return   re1.test(el.hashtags);
});
console.log(delete_id1);
```

Comment: I already can filter which object has 'land' in its title. I need to filter the objects if they have 'land' in the title or hashtags

Comment: what is tehy ?.

Comment: i think you've misunderstood my question. the return needs to be one array.

Comment: @Mahi How is `javascript` at Answer different from http://stackoverflow.com/a/40586426/ ?

Comment: i didn't check your answer because you didn't provide fiddle before

Comment: @Mahi you have 2 variables of 2 new arrays. I asked for a single array which is the filtered version of the original array.

Comment: @saunders last one array is what you want . it is same as above answer . but i took different array to store value .